# Numerical Solution of Systems of PDE

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

Could someone give me some reference  to the Numerical solution of a System of PDEs  of following type.. (which also encompasses strongly elliptic system of PDEs) in 2D or 3D.

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \mathrm{div} (\mathbf{U}_k)=f_k ,  \text{ for } k=1,\ldots,M 
\\ 
&\mathbf{U}_k = \sum^M_{l=1}B_{kl} \cdot \mathrm{grad\,}  P_l ,\text{ for } k=1,\ldots,M
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

where $B_{kl}$ is a matrix of appropriate dimension.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\dualp}[2]{{\langle {#1},{#2} \rangle}}$
$\newcommand{\v}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$

As far as I know, if you are using [finite element methods on an unstructured mesh](http://capfluidicslit.mme.pdx.edu/reference/Numerics/Finite%20element%20method/Geuzain_IJNME2009_gmsh.pdf), there are two types of approach available, suppose we have a polygonal/polyhedral domain $\Omega$ triangulated by a set of triangles/tetrahedra in 2D/3D respectively, and proper boundary conditions are assumed for the PDEs.

- First is *mixed finite element method(MFEM)*, the numerical method for strongly elliptic equation system shares the same core idea with the MFEM for diffusion equation $-\mathrm{div}(D\, \mathbf{grad} \,u) = f$, rewrite this second order PDE as a first order system:
  $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
  &D^{-1}\,\boldsymbol{\sigma} + \mathbf{grad} \,u &= 0 
  \\
  & \mathrm{div} \boldsymbol{\sigma} &=f
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  which falls into the framework of the following saddle point problem:
  $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{l}
  &A\boldsymbol{\sigma} + B^T \,u &= \v{g} &\text{ in } V'
  \\
  & B\boldsymbol{\sigma} &=f &\text{ in } Q'
  \end{array}\right.
  $$
  where $V$ and $Q$ are two Hilbert spaces, in this case $V = H(\mathrm{div},\Omega)$ and $Q = L^2(\Omega)$. The variational formulation is

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
&\dualp{A\v{\sigma}}{\v{\tau}} + \dualp{\v{\tau}}{B^T \,u} &= \dualp{\v{g}}{\v{\tau}} &\forall \v{\tau}\in V
\\
& \dualp{B\boldsymbol{\sigma}}{q} &=\dualp{f}{q} &\forall q\in Q
\end{array}\right.
$$
Take the test function space be a finite dimensional space $V_h$, either Raviart-Thomas or Brezzi-Douglas-Marini element(conforming) or other nonconforming spaces, and you have the MFEM formulation, for detail please refer to [Mixed and Hybrid Finite Element Methods](http://books.google.com/books/about/Mixed_and_hybrid_finite_element_methods.html?id=yYwZAQAAIAAJ) by Brezzi and Fortin, in your case it is:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
&\dualp{B^{-1}\mathbf{U}_k}{\mathbf{V}_k} - \dualp{\mathbf{V}_k}{\mathbf{grad} P} &= 0 &\forall \,\mathbf{V}_k
\\
& \dualp{\mathrm{div}{\mathbf{U}_k}}{q_k} &=\dualp{f_k}{q_k} &\forall q_k
\end{array}\right.
$$

- Second is *least-square finite element method(LSFEM)*, Google scholar gives me this as the most cited paper: [First-Order System Least Squares for Second-Order Partial Differential Equations](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2158377), and a recent review is [this](https://cfwebprod.sandia.gov/cfdocs/CCIM/docs/gunzburger.pdf). The idea is, if we still use the diffusion equation as example, we would like to minimize the following least-square functional over appropriate finite element spaces:
  $$
  \mathcal{J}(v,\v{\tau}) = \|\v{\tau}+D\mathbf{grad}v\|^2_{\boldsymbol{L}^2(\Omega)} + \|\mathrm{div}\v{\tau} - f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
  $$
  In your case, the LS functional you would like to minimize is 
  $$
  \mathcal{J}(\mathbf{V}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{V}_M,Q_1,\ldots,Q_M) = \sum_k \|\mathbf{V}_k - D\mathbf{grad}Q_k\|^2_{\boldsymbol{L}^2(\Omega)} + \sum_k \|\mathrm{div}\mathbf{V}_k - f_k\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
  $$